# How to disable Bootstrap nav-item using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I'm building a webapp using Flask, and I'm using jinja templates to present different pages unified by an always-present navbar. When the user clicks on a given link -- "About", for instance -- and Flask loads the template for the "About" page, I want the `About` link in the navbar disabled.

I've tried to implement this via simple JavaScript in each template, but I can't get the clicked link to be disabled. Here is a section from my `layout.html` document, where the navbar is established:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a
            class="nav-link"
            onclick="cookieManager()"
            href="/about"
            id="abt"
            >about</a
            >
    </li>
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
{% block main %}

    <script>
        const aboutBtn = document.querySelector(".nav-item [id=abt]");
        aboutBtn.classlist.add("disabled");
    </script>

    <h3>This is the About page</h3>
{% endblock %}
```

This gives me an error in the console saying that the `add` property of `aboutBtn` is undefined. However, if I log `aboutBtn` to console after declaring it, it does exist.

Comment: It should be `aboutBtn.classList.add("disabled");`

Comment: @Unmitigated wow. And that solves that. I should have been looking closer. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help. (filler text)